# ¿Cómo puedo reparar este ciclo if para que haga la verificación?

Tags: c, linux

Siguiendo con el desarollo del programa y corrigiendo errores (quiero hacer un programa que pueda administrar facilmente, para el usuario, el programa iptables en Linux).

Ahora me topo con que el programa al momento de hacer la verificación de lo que introduce el usuario en el scanf() pasa totalmente a la ejecución de la parte else.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
        char a[66];
        char help[3] = "-h";
        printf("Por favor introduzca la orden. Si desea ver la ayuda introduzca -h:\n");
        scanf("%c", &a);
        if ( a == help)
         printf("\n\nComandos y expresiones de iptables:"); 
        else 
        system("export COMANDO='a'");
        char ipt[66] = "iptables $COMANDO && iptables -L -v -n";
        system(ipt); 
        return 0; }
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el if y el else funcionen bien para que en la función system() se pueda exportar el valor de "a" y que eso sea ejecutado por el segundo system() para poder funcionar bien?

Answer (score 2):

Hombre, no puedes comparar arreglos de caracteres tan simple... Aparte de que tus llaves del else no las colocaste...

```
    char a[66];
    char help[3] = "-h";
    scanf("%c", &a);

    if ( a == help)
```

Lo que debes hacer es esto

```
int main () {
    char a[66];
    char help[3] = "-h";
    printf("Por favor introduzca la orden. Si desea ver la ayuda introduzca -h:\n");
    scanf("%65s", &a);
    if (strcmp(a,help) == 0)
     printf("\n\nComandos y expresiones de iptables:");
    else {
        system("export COMANDO= 'a'");
        char ipt[66] = "iptables $COMANDO && iptables -L -v -n";
        system(ipt);
    }

    return 0;
```

}

strcmp te regresa un entero con valor de cero si las cadenas son iguales. Aparte de que cuando ingresas la variable lo pones como:

```
 scanf("%c", &a);
```

donde le estas diciendo que solo ingrese un caracter... si quieres ingresar una cadena se coloca "%s" y ya que tu arreglo tiene 66 (ó 65 realmente) caracteres puedes colocar "%65s" para no desbordar tu arreglo...

```
scanf("%65s", &a);
```

Saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

La sentencia if, else al no encerrar el bloque de instrucciones en llaves ejecuta solo la primera linea, prueba con la siguiente corrección.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
    char a[66];
    char help[3] = "-h";
    printf("Por favor introduzca la orden. Si desea ver la ayuda introduzca -h:\n");
    scanf("%c", &a);
    if ( a == help)
        printf("\n\nComandos y expresiones de iptables:"); 
    else {
        system("export COMANDO=" + std::string(a) );
        char ipt[66] = "iptables $COMANDO && iptables -L -v -n";
        system(ipt); 
        return 0; 
    }
}
```

Comment: No funciona, por que si yo pongo -h salta a la ejecución del segundo system (sin poder saber si el primero se ejecuto) y si pongo otro comando (que es lo que tendria que dar lugar al else) dice en el iptables que no se ha especificado el comando, por lo que el primer system no esta funcionando (ahora veo como arreglarlo algo se me ocurre ahora)

Comment: Es cierto eso es por que el primer system ejecuta "export COMANDO='a'" de forma literal es decir sin considerar a 'a' como una variable, añadi esa corrección a la respuesta.

Comment: Da este error gcc con esa modificacion; invalid operands of types ‘const char [17]’ and ‘char [66]’ to binary ‘operator+’
  system("export COMANDO='" + a + " '");

Comment: Hice una segunda corrección la sintaxis correcta es sin comillas simples, le añadi un parseo a string si no funciona prueba únicamente con + a, ahora mismo no tengo como probar el código.

Comment: Vuelve a tirar un error de operación invalida de tipos (el mismo error que el último). Me cuesta creer que se complique tanto el pasar una variable local como dato a la función system.